# Unable to restrict access to Apache 2.4 Reverse Proxy on SSL by IP

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, apache-config

I'm trying to restrict access to a reverse proxy on my Apache 2.4 server. It works on http but not on https.

I set up a ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse on / to another server, and have 2 .conf files which contain the same Require ip line. The http reverse proxy works, but the https one says "client denied by server configuration.

Server is 10.0.1.1, the endpoint is 10.0.1.2.

http_vhost.conf

```
<Location />
   Require ip 10.0.0.0/16
</Location>
ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.2/
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.2/
```

https_vhost.conf

```
<Location />
   Require ip 10.0.0.0/16
</Location>
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass / http://10.0.1.2/
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.1.2/
```

Accessing the http_vhost from a 10.0.1.100 ip address, vhost works as intended. Site content on 10.0.1.2 shows as intended.

Accessing the https_vhost from the same 10.0.1.100 ip address, vhost content shows

```
Forbidden. You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

https_vhost shows the following in the access.log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2019:12:47:21 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 6692 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"
```

But shows the following in the error.log:

```
[Wed Aug 14 12:48:04.604656 2019] [authz_core:error] [pid 4671] [client 127.0.0.1:54607] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: http://10.0.1.2/
```

The access.log entry for the http server is:

```
mydomain.com:80 10.0.1.100 - - [14/Aug/2019:18:13:35 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 348 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"
```

When I comment the "Require ip" line, both http and https work as intended.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: Is there any other difference between `http_site.conf` and `https_site.conf`?

Comment: the only difference between ```http_site.conf``` and ```https_site.conf``` is the declaration of port 80 vs 443, and the SSLEngine + SSLCertificateFile lines..

But as far as restriction is concerned, the Require line is the only gamechanger..

Comment: Can you show the access log line from successful http request

Comment: from the http request, the access log line is:

```vhost.mydomain.com:80 10.0.1.100 - - [14/Aug/2019:18:13:35 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 348 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"```

Comment: I might want to mention the 2 entries are vhosts, the server has multiple vhosts it is reverse proxy'ing, but it's the first time I'm encountering this problem as there is a request to restrict access to one particular vhost by IP address.

Comment: In your denied https request, the source IP address is logged as 127.0.0.1 .....

Comment: In your allowed http request, the source IP address is logged as 10.0.1.100 ....

Comment: Yes, that's what puzzles me..

Comment: Can you share full .conf file contents?

Comment: I found out why SSL are coming in from 127.0.0.1. I'm also using SSLH, which allows me to SSH thru the same port, allowing me to close port 22, avoiding most of the brute-force attacks.

Updated my SSLH version, made some configuration updates, and turned on Transparent mode, and now the IP address is passed on to Apache properly.

Question closed. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

I found out why SSL are coming in from 127.0.0.1. I'm also using SSLH, which allows me to SSH thru the same port, allowing me to close port 22, avoiding most of the brute-force attacks.

Updated my SSLH version, made some configuration updates, and turned on Transparent mode, and now the IP address is passed on to Apache properly.

Question closed. Thanks for all the help!